# Logging out while viewing my recent activity causes a 404

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

No big deal, this has just been bugging me.  Whenever I try to log out while viewing my recent activity (the little envelope up top), It always returns a 404.  Viewing another page confirms I am logged out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you must be logged in to view that page. It is private to you.

Comment: It would be better to redirect the user to (for example) the homepage rather than a 404 page if a user logs out while looking at a page which is inaccessible as an anonymous user.

Comment: That makes sense.  A redirect might be a good idea though.  Thanks!