# Logging out redirecting to "page not found"

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

When logging out of SO and was directed to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout/global?returnurl=/), and when i log back in i am directed to the same page although i am still logged in as i can see my username and rep.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior or know how to rectify it?

Addendum: I have been made aware that this is common when logging out as some pages are not viewable when not logged in, this does not answer why it continued to happen when logging back in?

Comment: You can log-out any time you like, but you can never leave.

Comment: It depends on where you're going.  There are some places you're only allowed to see when you're logged in.  Logging out from those pages presents a 404.  See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69654/logging-out-while-viewing-my-recent-activity-causes-a-404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened because we erroneously redirect you to a page that was a 404 (at that time).  We now won't redirect you in this condition.

---

*Long version:*
We're switching some authentication paths to SSL (global auth in this case), that caused an unexpected overload of our nginx server running on the primary load balancer.  Across the network we get a *lot* of requests for global auth (over 2 million a day)...turns out our configuration wasn't quite prepared for that amount of load (specifically, the socket pool ran dry pretty quick).

The short-term fix for that is simple: lower the load, in this case that meant disabling global auth on Stack Overflow (it accounts for ~1.5million of those ~2.2 million requests per day).  The problem here? Disabling global auth *didn't disable that specific logout redirect*, that piece has been corrected.

We've now adjusted the SSL configuration we're running (as we'll continue too) and global auth is up and running again.  We'll be keeping an eye on it all day just in case...if something goes very wrong you may notice global auth on SO disabled again, but no erroneous redirects.

Comment: How could i not accept that?! Thanks for the clarification Nick.