# "Page Not Found" when logging out on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When logging out of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) I am redirected to "`http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/logout/global?returnurl=/`" automatically -- but unfortunately this URL does not exist and a *Page Not Found Error (404)* is displayed:

[image: Area51 404 Error]

This question seems to be similar to [Logging out redirecting to “page not found”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118608/298869) on Stack Overflow, although on Area 51 the log out as such is done correctly.

Is this a common problem on Area 51 or I am the only one experiencing this?

Comment: Whoops, yeah, that's a bug. Hang on, fixing.

Comment: @AdamLear: Is it also because of some SSL configuration problems?

Comment: Nah, not at all. We removed the `/users/logout/global` route, but missed that redirect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. We removed the `/users/logout/global` route, but missed that redirect to it. The fix is out now.

Comment: No problem at all. Yes it works now perfectly. Redirected to the Area 51 main page :)